# How to included bundled rulesets in maven pmd plugin

Tags: maven, pmd

I have a custom ruleset definition that refers to a bunch of rules from bundled rulesets. However, I have problems with resolving these bundled rulesets in the maven pmd plugin. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389612/maven-pmd-plugin-uses-only-the-bundled-rulesets) is a related question with a quick'n'dirty solution for this problem. However, I was wondering whether there might be a clean solution for this problem (because I think that this is a rather common usecase, or?).
In the following I'm describing the attempts that I tried so far:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>my_pmd_ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.source.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

1. I defined the maven pmd plugin (version 3.0.1) with my custom ruleset (and Java 1.6) in build/plugin management section of my parent pom as well as in the reporting section. I got many of the following warnings:

   ```
    [WARNING] Failure executing PMD: Unable to find referenced rule UnusedModifier; 
    perhaps the rule name is mispelled?
   ```
2. I tried to refer to all utilised bundled rulesets:

   ```
   <build>
   <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                   <rulesets>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/coupling.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/design.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/controversial.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/codesize.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/clone.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/braces.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/basic.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/finalizers.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/imports.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/unit.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/logging-jakarta-commons.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/logging-java.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/migrating.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/naming.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/optimizations.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/strictexception.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/strings.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/sunsecure.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/typeresolution.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml</ruleset>
                       <ruleset>my_pmd_ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                   </rulesets>
                   <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                   <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                   <target>${java.source.version}</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   ```

There I'm getting always the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1:pmd (pmd) on project my_project: An error has occurred in PMD Report report generation. Could not find resource 'rulesets/java/unit.xml'
```

The maven pmd plugin depends on pmd, so the bundled rulesets should be part of the classpath, or? The [Maven pmd plugin manual](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html) says that bundled rulesets should be defined with a relative path and custom rulesets with an absolute path. However, I think that it can also read my custom ruleset via a relative path, because it is part of the classpath.
I also tried other thing, e.g., explicit additional dependency definition of pmd in the maven pmd plugin. However, without any success so far :\

Comment: the error was completely different: 1. there was a typo in the _j_unit ruleset 2. one bundled rule was moved from controversial ruleset to unusedcode ruleset 3. it is good to utilise following properties in the maven pmd configuration section: maxAllowedViolations, violationSeverity, failOnViolation and failsOnError (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106767/maven-checkstylecheck-not-working)

Comment: btw, on doesn't need to load the bundled rulesets separately, when they are referred in the custom ruleset